# k-means clustering algorithm implementation

Tags: python, reinventing-the-wheel, numpy, clustering, machine-learning

Here is my personal implementation of the clustering [k-means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) algorithm.

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
import numpy as np
import random

# (x,y) coordinates of a point
X = 0
Y = 1

def get_first(k, points):
    return points[0:k]

def cost(cetroids, clusters):
    cost = 0

    for i in range(len(centroids)):
        centroid = centroids[i]
        cluster = clusters[i]
        for point in cluster:
            cost += (distance.euclidean(centroid, point))**2

    return cost

def compute_centroids(clusters):
    centroids = []

    for cluster in clusters:
        centroids.append(np.mean(cluster, axis=0))

    return centroids


def kmeans(k, centroids, points, method, iter):
    clusters = [[] for i in range(k)]

    for i in range(len(points)):
        point = points[i]
        belongs_to_cluster = closest_centroid(point, centroids)
        clusters[belongs_to_cluster].append(point)

    new_centroids = compute_centroids(clusters)

    if not equals(centroids, new_centroids):
        print "Iteration " + str(iter) + ". Cost [k=" + str(k) + ", " + method + "] = " + str(cost(new_centroids, clusters))

        clusters = kmeans(k, new_centroids, points, method, iter+1)

    return clusters

def closest_centroid(point, centroids):
    min_distance = float('inf')
    belongs_to_cluster = None
    for j in range(len(centroids)):
        centroid = centroids[j]
        dist = distance.euclidean(point, centroid)
        if dist < min_distance:
            min_distance = dist
            belongs_to_cluster = j

    return belongs_to_cluster

def contains(point1, points):
    for point2 in points:
        if point1[X] == point2[X] and point1[Y] == point2[Y]:
            return True

    return False

def equals(points1, points2):
    if len(points1) != len(points2):
        return False

    for i in range (len(points1)):
        point1 = points1[i]
        point2 = points2[i]
        if point1[X] != point2[X] or point1[Y] != point2[Y]:
            return False

    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = [[-19.0748,     -8.536       ],
            [ 22.0108,      -10.9737    ],
            [ 12.6597,      19.2601     ],
            [ 11.26884087,  19.90132146 ],
            [ 15.44640731,  21.13121676 ],
            [-20.03865146,  -8.820872829],
            [-19.65417726,  -8.211477352],
            [-15.97295894,  -9.648002534],
            [-18.74359696,  -5.383551586],
            [-19.453215,    -8.146120006],
            [-16.43074088,  -7.524968005],
            [-19.75512437,  -8.533215751],
            [-19.56237082,  -8.798668569],
            [-19.47135573,  -8.057217004],
            [-18.60946986,  -4.475888949],
            [-21.59368337,  -10.38712463],
            [-15.39158057,  -3.8336522  ],
            [-40.0,          40.0       ]]
    k = 4

    # k-means picking the first k points as centroids
    centroids = get_first(k, data)
    clusters = kmeans(k, centroids, data, "first", 1)
```

I understood and followed the theory of the algorithm, but as you can see, when running the code, the cost on each iteration of the algorithm increases. I am new to python and I think the problem relies in some misunderstanding from my side regarding list manipulation. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some good answers.

Comment: Also, I am open to suggestions regarding the quality of my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

N.b. I'm pretty sure you can find optimised replacements of many of
these functions in either the NumPy or SciPy library.

Edit: I don't immediately see a reason for a slowdown except the
addition of new clusters.  A bigger sample set that shows the behaviour
would be nice, together with some timings and probably running a
profiler on it.

In general you should likely use a NumPy array or matrix instead of
lists of lists as they are optimised for storing numeric data(!).  That
would likely also eliminate the need for some of these functions or
considerably reduce their length.  Also store all data in the same
containers - that way you don't have to create new functions like
`equals` and `contains` yourself to compare between different
representations.

- The `X`/`Y` definitions at the start are more of a WTF for me.  I'd
  get rid of that by writing code that's either independent on the
  number of dimensions, or just use `0`/`1` - IMO it's not magic enough
  to warrant separate constants.
- `get_first` isn't neccessary - the pattern is obvious enough to not
  require encapsulation in a function.  The zero is also optional.
- Typo in `cost` signature, should be `centroids`.
- The pattern `for i in range(len(...)):` appears a couple of times and
  should be replaced with proper iteration over some helper generator.
  E.g. in `cost` the parallel iteration over both `centroids` and
  `clusters` should be done by `zip` (`itertools.izip` in Python 2.7 if
  used in the same way).  It can also be simplified by using another
  SciPy function,
  [`cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html).
- If you still need the index, use `enumerate`.
- You can also often get away with using the squared euclidean if the
  exact value isn't relevant, just the relation between different
  distances.
- The pattern to initialise a list of empty lists should probably use
  `_` instead of `i` to make it obvious that the variable serves to
  further purpose.
- `print` should be used as a function to make it more uniform.  Also,
  use one of the various formatting options (`%` or `format`) to get rid
  of the additional `str` calls.
- `compute_centroids` can be simplified with a list comprehension.

Looks like this now:

```py
from scipy.spatial import distance
import numpy as np
import random
from itertools import izip


def cost(centroids, clusters):
    return sum(distance.cdist([centroid], cluster, 'sqeuclidean').sum()
            for centroid, cluster in izip(centroids, clusters))


def compute_centroids(clusters):
    return [np.mean(cluster, axis=0) for cluster in clusters]


def kmeans(k, centroids, points, method):
    clusters = [[] for _ in range(k)]

    for point in points:
        clusters[closest_centroid(point, centroids)].append(point)

    new_centroids = compute_centroids(clusters)

    if not equals(centroids, new_centroids):
        print("cost [k={}, {}] = {}".format(k, method, cost(new_centroids, clusters)))

        clusters = kmeans(k, new_centroids, points, method)

    return clusters


def closest_centroid(point, centroids):
    min_distance = float('inf')
    belongs_to_cluster = None
    for j, centroid in enumerate(centroids):
        dist = distance.sqeuclidean(point, centroid)
        if dist < min_distance:
            min_distance = dist
            belongs_to_cluster = j

    return belongs_to_cluster


def contains(point1, points):
    for point2 in points:
        if point1[0] == point2[0] and point1[1] == point2[1]:
        # if all(x == y for x, y in izip(points1, points2)):
            return True

    return False


def equals(points1, points2):
    if len(points1) != len(points2):
        return False

    for point1, point2 in izip(points1, points2):
        if point1[0] != point2[0] or point1[1] != point2[1]:
        # if any(x != y for x, y in izip(points1, points2)):
            return False

    return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = [[-19.0748,     -8.536       ],
            [ 22.0108,      -10.9737    ],
            [ 12.6597,      19.2601     ],
            [ 11.26884087,  19.90132146 ],
            [ 15.44640731,  21.13121676 ],
            [-20.03865146,  -8.820872829],
            [-19.65417726,  -8.211477352],
            [-15.97295894,  -9.648002534],
            [-18.74359696,  -5.383551586],
            [-19.453215,   -8.146120006],
            [-16.43074088,  -7.524968005],
            [-19.75512437,  -8.533215751],
            [-19.56237082,  -8.798668569],
            [-19.47135573,  -8.057217004],
            [-18.60946986,  -4.475888949],
            [-21.59368337,  -10.38712463],
            [-15.39158057,  -3.8336522  ],
            [-40.0,          40.0       ]]
    k = 4

    # k-means picking the first k points as centroids
    centroids = data[:k]
    clusters = kmeans(k, centroids, data, "first")
```

Comment: This is... just prodigious. Sharp, neat and complete answer. I will revise the whole thing tomorrow morning. Thanks a lot @ferada.